# How to use aerospike with testcontainers on github actions

Tags: go, testcontainers, aerospike

I am trying to run aerospike on testcontainers with github actions,

I am sometimes getting an error and sometimes not when I run this on github actions, the error i got is below,

```
integration_test.go:124: error getting aerospike client: error creating cluster client: aero client failed to connect to [127.0.0.1]:32772 timeout:10s: ResultCode: INVALID_NODE_ERROR, Iteration: 0, InDoubt: false, Node: <nil>: Failed to connect to hosts: [127.0.0.1:32772]
```

My aerospike config is below,

```
service {
    user root
    group root
    # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
    # paxos-single-replica-limit 1
    # pidfile /var/run/aerospike/asd.pid
    proto-fd-max 15000
    query-threads-limit 100
}

logging {
    # Log file must be an absolute path.
    file ${LOGFILE} {
        context any critical
    }

    # Send log messages to stdout
    console {
        context any info
    }
}

network {
    service {
        address any
        port 3000

        # Uncomment the following to set the `access-address` parameter to the
        # IP address of the Docker host. This will the allow the server to correctly
        # publish the address which applications and other nodes in the cluster to
        # use when addressing this node.
        # access-address <IPADDR>
    }

    heartbeat {
        address any
        # mesh is used for environments that do not support multicast
        mode mesh
        port 3002

        # use asinfo -v 'tip:host=<ADDR>;port=3002' to inform cluster of
        # other mesh nodes

        interval 150
        timeout 10
    }

    fabric {
        address any
        port 3001 
    }
}

namespace persistent00 {
  replication-factor 1
  memory-size 20M
  storage-engine memory
  nsup-period 86400
}
```

This is how i connect via using test containers,

```
func startContainer(ctx context.Context) (*aerospikeContainer, error) {
    req := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Image:        "aerospike/aerospike-server:6.2.0.12",
        ExposedPorts: []string{"3000/tcp", "3001/tcp", "3002/tcp"},
        Files: []testcontainers.ContainerFile{
            {
                HostFilePath:      "aerospike.conf",
                ContainerFilePath: "aerospike.conf",
            },
        },
        Cmd: []string{"--config-file", "aerospike.conf"},
        WaitingFor: wait.ForAll(
            wait.ForListeningPort("3000/tcp"),
            wait.ForLog("{persistent00} migrations: complete").WithOccurrence(2),
        ),
    }

    container, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: req,
        Started:          true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &aerospikeContainer{Container: container}, nil
}
```

What should I do to make it work?

I tried to use heartbeats and increased `withOccurence` but it still seems to not work

Comment: I would think your use of `WaitingFor` would have worked. If I understand you correctly, it never works in GitHub actions and sometimes does not work locally.  You could try to add a retry mechanism to your `client.connect()` and see if that improves your chance of connecting locally. I'd recommend a high number of retries like 20 with 1 sec of sleep in between to start debugging

Answer (score 0):

This thread suggests to upgrade the client (in your case Go client) to the latest version when encountering `INVALID_NODE_ERROR`: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/invalid-node-error-code-3-after-some-writes/6037/9

JDogMcSteezy's comment makes sense if it happens sometimes and not always (client is trying to connect to Aerospike before Aerospike is reachable), `waitingFor` should help in this case.

I'm not familiar with Go, but you can see a stable Java example of using Aerospike with testcontainers which utilizes Playtika's public library to use testcontainers with Aerospike here: https://github.com/aerospike/spring-data-aerospike

Playtika's testcontainers dependency: https://github.com/aerospike/spring-data-aerospike/blob/main/pom.xml#L256

This is a configuration file for testcontainers, it only contains Aerospike's version by default: https://github.com/aerospike/spring-data-aerospike/blob/main/src/test/resources/bootstrap.properties

And this is the configuration class in tests: https://github.com/aerospike/spring-data-aerospike/blob/main/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/aerospike/config/BlockingTestConfig.java#L30